# Bitbucket:git checkout to a particular rivision from remote as a new barnch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to check out a particular revision from the remote branch `testing` as new local branch.

```
git checkout cf15dd0dcb0c8b0de0bd0c96c9cfaa897c961715 -b milestone2-fixes  origin/testing
```

But i got the following error

```
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'milestone2' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/testing' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

But `git branch -r` gives all of my remote branches

Here is the output

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
origin/milestone3
origin/testing
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Create a new branch?  Reset an existing branch to a commit?  Something else?

Comment: Create a new branch from that particular commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given `git checkout` *three* items of interest (I have changed the order here a bit for discussion purposes, but the effect is the same):

1. `-b milestone2-fixes`
2. `cf15dd0dcb0c8b0de0bd0c96c9cfaa897c961715`
3. `origin/testing`

The first part, `-b milestone2-fixes`, tells `git checkout` that it should create a new branch and switch to that branch, which is fine.  However, this form of `git checkout`—i.e., using `-b`—can take *at most one additional* item of interest.  You must choose which additional item to drop.

You may run:

- `git checkout -b milestone2-fixes cf15dd0dcb0c8b0de0bd0c96c9cfaa897c961715`

  This creates the branch with commit `cf15dd0dcb0c8b0de0bd0c96c9cfaa897c961715` as its hash ID, checking out commit `cf15dd0dcb0c8b0de0bd0c96c9cfaa897c961715` in the process.  The new branch has no upstream set.
- `git checkout -b milestone2-fixes origin/testing`

  This creates the branch with whatever hash ID `origin/testing` has as the new branch's hash ID, checking out that commit in the process.  The new branch has `origin/testing` set as its upstream.

If `origin/testing` resolves to hash ID `cf15dd0dcb0c8b0de0bd0c96c9cfaa897c961715`, the second form of the command does everything you want at once.  If not, use the first form of the command, and if you still want `origin/testing` set as the new branch's upstream, use `git branch --set-upstream-to` to set that afterward.

Comment: I don't think we really the full 40 character SHA-1 hash.  10 characters would probably suffice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the OP included all, who am I to say how many commits are in the repo? If it has trillions of commits we might need very long hashes. :-) But shorter is probably fine, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Leave off the remote branch name and swap order of arguments:

```
git checkout -b milestone2-fixes cf15dd0dcb0c8b0de0bd0c96c9cfaa897c961715
```

The syntax is: `checkout -b <new branch name> <starting point>`. No need for the remote branch name, because you already specify one exact commit.